# Does ClojureScript project need a process manager?

Tags: clojurescript

I want to start a project that using `Node.js+Express.js+ClojureScript` in light of https://gist.github.com/jneira/1171737 . But I am afraid that if I deploy the project to production environment, it should be protected by a process manager, like `pm2` in a `Node.js` project.

As far as I know, `pm2` is needed by a `Node.js` project because that `Javascript` in `Node.js` is single-threaded, so exception will cause `Node.js` apps to halt. `pm2` will protect the app and make it running forever.

But does a `ClojureScript` project running in `Node.js` need a process manager? If so, how should I do the work like `pm2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ClojureScript compiles to javascript there is no difference in the tooling you can use to manage the node.js process. You can just follow the normal pm2 instructions if you want to use [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). If you are running a web server I'd suggest you also check out [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/).

And on the actual *need* to use a process manager, and which manager to use in that case: Those are depending a lot on personal taste / opinion.